# Create a pyspark dataframe from dict_values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, pyspark

I am trying to generate a pyspark dataframe out of dict_values. I can achieve the same using pandas concate function. and dictionary consist of key as year and value as pyspark dataframe.

Here is my code which i am using i have one alternative to union all all the dataframe which i believe not the better way to achieve it.

```
dict_ym = {}
for yearmonth in keys:    
    key_name = 'df_'+str(yearmonth)
    dict_ym[key_name]= df
    # Add a new column to dataframe
    # Perform some more transformation

dict_ym 

# Now above dict has key as yearmonth for eg. 201501 and value as dataframe consit of 10 columns

def union_all_dataframes(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)

df2 = union_all_dataframes(dict_ym['df_201501'],dict_ym['df_201502'] ... so on till dict_ym['df_201709'])
```

But in pandas dataframe i can do something like this which will append all the dataframes one below to others using below set of code:

```
 df2 = pd.concat(dict_ym.values()) # here dict_ym has pandas dataframe in case of spark df
```

I think their would be more elegant to create pyspark dataframe as well similar as `pandas.concat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
df2 = union_all_dataframes(*dict_ym.values())
```